# Prove that the space $C_{c}^{0}(\Omega)$ is dense

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to show the **Lemma** in my book:

> *The space $C_{c}^{0}(\Omega)$ is **dense** in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $1 \le p < \infty$*.

---

I tried to use the definitions:

- $C_{c}^{0}(\Omega)=\{f:\Omega \to \Bbb R, \ f \ \text{is continuous, with compact support in $\Omega$}\}$
- $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\overline{\{x \in \Omega:f(x)\ne 0\}}$
- Set $A$ is **dense** in $X$ iff $\overline{A}=X $. It means that $\forall x \in X, \exists \{a_n\}\subset A:a_n \to x$

But I have no solution :(.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem

Comment: @ **Prahlad Vaidyanathan**: What the...?

Comment: What I meant was that this is a direct corollary of Lusin's theorem - in fact, this very fact is proved in almost any reasonable book on measure theory.

Comment: I'm sorry! But in my book, it doesn't have a solution.

Comment: As you said, I should read a proof of this lemma in another book? Can you recommend me name of the book? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis"

Comment: Thanks **Prahlad Vaidyanathan**!

Answer (score 0):

And I found in the book: [Epsilon of Room, I: Real Analysis](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=DhWarYBllZAC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=Let%20C_c%20be%20the%20space%20of%20continuous%20functions%20with%20compact%20support%20on%20R%5En%20then%20C_c%20is%20dense%20%20in%20L%5Ep&source=bl&ots=TFc8c3kWT6&sig=DRJR4n8qMsiCowFPuRKj192YjVk&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=EXxnUtGyK86UiQfF4YGYBQ&ved=0CGYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=true).

[image: Solution]